# Angularjs directive for checkbox with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that work on check-box that also has ng-model.
In the directive on link function the check box not get the value of the model.
It is work if add timeout( doesn't matter how long, even with 0 ).

My control and directive:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[])
.directive("checkBox", function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            console.log("Check box is : " + element[0].checked);
            scope.message += "Check box is : " + element[0].checked + " , ";
            $timeout(function(){
                scope.message += "Check box is : " + element[0].checked;    
                console.log("Check box is : " + element[0].checked);
            },0);
        }
    }
});

function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.checkBoxModel = true;
    $scope.message = "";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkBoxModel" check-box>
        <br/>
        {{message}}
</div>
```

Fiddel - http://jsfiddle.net/myyjL/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You probably should not do what you are trying to do, but it is possible.

Here is a plunkr that works, without timeout:

http://jsfiddle.net/myyjL/2/

```
.directive("checkBox", ['$timeout', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            ngModel:'='
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue){
                scope.$parent.message = 'Checkbox value is: ' + newValue;
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

The problem with that approach is that your directive knows about stuff that is outside of it (as in the {{message}} variable). That is a bad design and you should rework that. Also, in your fiddle you use the element[0].checked, while you can easily use the ng-modal value. But the ng-modal might not be there. Also, the input might not be a real checkbox, so your approach also fails. How to fix that? I'm gonna write you a demonstrative plunkr in a sec:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jyY6sQwXmtlGOvpdzETR?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.directive('box', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'box.tpl.html',
        replace: true
    };
}])

.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function MyController($scope){
    $scope.checkboxValue = true;
}]);
```

What we did here is make sure our directive is always a checkbox by providing the checkbox inside the template. The you are able to do styling etc, of your directive.

Comment: Hi Baba.
Thanks for answer. I know that use stuff outside of the directive is not good design. I add this only for the example for showing the false / true on the screen...
About the watch - i don't want to do something every time the model is change. only on directive load, and i need to know if the check box is checked or not.

Comment: There are other directives you can use: ng-load and ng-init. You shouldn't be using $timeout.

Comment: Of course I Don't want to use $timeout. that why i ask this question. to understand way after this timeout of zero the checkbox get the value.. if i use ng-load or ng-init i miss the directive point.. i dont want to add ng-init for each check box.

Comment: As I told your directive is missing the biggest point: that it might not be applied on a checkbox but on another type of control, which would make it completely useless. That is why you should just create a directive which wraps a checkbox and put the ng-init and ng-load inside it. That way you'd just do <box ng-model='value'></box>, just like in my plunkr. That way you'd be sure that your directive ALWAYS  is applied on a checkbox. And you get the value after the timeout because of how the $scope.$apply/$digest cycle works.

Comment: Besides, your directive doesn't do anything but to set scope's message. I doubt it can be useful for anything, besides this you can do also with ng-init, which wouldn't require you to depend on the apply/digest lifecycle: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope